# Why a waiting thread does not wake up after calling notify?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, condition-variable

I am trying to simulate a sensor that outputs data at a certain frame rate while another is waiting to have a data ready and when it is ready it copies it locally and processes it.

```
Sensor sensor(1,1000);
Monitor monitor;

// Function that continuously reads data from sensor
void runSensor()
{
    // Initial delay
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE_LOOP; i++)
    {
        monitor.captureData<Sensor>(sensor, &Sensor::captureData);
    }
}

// Function that waits until sensor data is ready
void waitSensor()
{
    monitor.saveData<Sensor>(sensor, &Sensor::saveData);
}

// Main function
int main()
{
    // Threads that reads at some frame rate data from sensor
    std::thread threadRunSensor(runSensor);

    // Processing loop
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE_LOOP; i++)
    {
        // Wait until data from sensor is ready
        std::thread threadWaitSensor(waitSensor);

        // Wait until data is copied
        threadWaitSensor.join();

        // Process synchronized data while sensor are throwing new data
        std::cout << "Init processing (" << sensor.getData() << /*"," << sensor2.getData() << */")"<< std::endl;
        // Sleep to simulate processing load
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10000 + (rand() % 1000)));
        //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        std::cout << "End processing" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the sensor class. It has two methods. One that generates the data and other that copies the data locally.

```
class Sensor
{
    private:

    int counter;
    int id;
    int frameRate;
    int dataCaptured;
    int dataSaved;

    public:

    Sensor(int f_id, int f_frameRate)
    {
        id = f_id;
        counter = 0;
        frameRate = f_frameRate;
    };

    ~Sensor(){};

    void captureData()
    {
        dataCaptured = counter;
        counter ++;
        std::cout << "Sensor" << id << " (" << dataCaptured << ")"<< std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(frameRate + (rand() % 500)));
    };

    void saveData()
    {
        dataSaved = dataCaptured;
        std::cout << "Copying sensor" << id << " (" << dataSaved << ")"<< std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1 + (rand() % 5)));
    }

    int getData()
    {
        return dataSaved;
    }
};
```

Then there is a class Monitor that ensures these operations are protected to concurrent accesses.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>

#define SIZE_LOOP 1000

class Monitor
{
private:

    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_condVar;
    bool m_isReady;

public:

    Monitor()
    {
        init();
    };

    ~Monitor()
    {
    };

    void init() 
    {
        m_isReady = false;
    };

    template<class T>
    void captureData(T& objectCaptured, void (T::* f_captureFunction_p)())
    {
        // Lock read
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m_mutex);
        (objectCaptured.*f_captureFunction_p)();
        m_isReady = true;
        m_condVar.notify_one();
        lock.unlock();
    };

    template<class T>
    void saveData(T& objectSaved, void(T::*f_saveFunction_p)())
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m_mutex);
        while(!m_isReady)
        {
            m_condVar.wait(lock);
        }
        (objectSaved.*f_saveFunction_p)();
        m_isReady = false;
        lock.unlock();
    };
};
```

Can anyone tell me why the waiting thread does not wakeup if the sensor is notifyng every frame rate?

The idea is having two threads with this workflow:

- ThreadCapture captures a data consinuously notifying to ThreadProcessing when the data capture is done.
- ThreadCapture must waits to capture a new data only if the current captured data is being copied on ThreadProcessing.
- ThreadProcessing waits to a new captured data, makes a local copy, notifies to ThreadCapture that the copy is done and process the data.
- The local copy is made on ThreadProcessing to allow ThreadCapture can capture new data while ThreadProcessing is processing.

Comment: Is notify_one ever called?

Comment: every second @Surt

Comment: You created an infinite loop by always saying you're not ready:  while(!m_isReady) { m_condVar.wait(lock); **m_isReady = false;** }

Comment: @RaymondChen you were right, my fault, but it is the same if I put it out.

Comment: Have you tried setting up break points in a debugger and confirming that the notification code is actually reached, and that soon afterward the thread doesn't resume execution (i.e. return from the `join`).

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Yes I tried it and it pass trought the join but just a few times. It should pass every time a notify is launched.

Comment: If two `captureData` calls happen quickly, then you set `m_isReady = true` twice, but the second one has no effect (setting a variable to a value it already has). If you want two `captureData` calls to release two threads, then `m_isReady` should be an integer count of "number of threads to wake up", not a boolean, which can wake only one thread.

Comment: @RaymondChen the idea is having just two threads with this functionallity:
 1. Thread1 captures a data consinuously notifying to Thread2 when the cata capture is done. 2. Thread1 must waits to capture a new data only if the current captured data is being copied on Thread2.
3. Thread2 waits to a new captured data, makes a local copy, notifies to Thread1 that the copy is done and process the data.

4. The local copy is made on Thread2 to allow Thread1 can capture new data while Thread2 is processing.

Comment: Notice that the lock is held during the producer's sleep_for. The producer releases the lock only for a very brief time before reacquiring it. This does not give the consumer very much opportunity to acquire the lock and read the data.

Comment: @RaymondChen You are right. Capturing thread is locking and unlocking the data continuously. But I do not find any solution that satisfyes the functionallity I want. Do you have an alternative?

Comment: Only you know what your rules are. You wrote the code so that the capturing thread holds the lock while sleeping for the next frame. Is that required by your rules? Or can you release the lock while sleeping?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution adding a waiting step after the capture to give time to save data

```
template<class T>
void captureData(T& objectCaptured, void (T::* f_captureFunction_p)())
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lockReady = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m_mutexReady, std::defer_lock);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lockProcess = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m_mutexProcess, std::defer_lock);

    // Lock, capture, set data ready flag, unlock and notify
    lockReady.lock();
    (objectCaptured.*f_captureFunction_p)();
    m_isReady = true;
    lockReady.unlock();
    m_conditionVariable.notify_one();
    
    // Wait while data is ready and it is not being processed
    lockReady.lock();
    lockProcess.lock();
    while(m_isReady && !m_isProcessing)
    {
        lockProcess.unlock();
        m_conditionVariable.wait(lockReady);
        lockProcess.lock();
    }
    lockProcess.unlock();
    lockReady.unlock();
};

template<class T>
void saveData(T& objectSaved, void(T::*f_saveFunction_p)())
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lockReady(m_mutexReady, std::defer_lock);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lockProcess(m_mutexProcess, std::defer_lock);

    // Reset processing
    lockProcess.lock();
    m_isProcessing = false;
    lockProcess.unlock();

    // Wait until data is ready
    lockReady.lock();
    while(!m_isReady)
    {
        m_conditionVariable.wait(lockReady);
    }

    // Make a copy of the data, reset ready flag, unlock and notify
    (objectSaved.*f_saveFunction_p)();
    m_isReady = false;
    lockReady.unlock();
    m_conditionVariable.notify_one();

    // Set processing
    lockProcess.lock();
    m_isProcessing = true;
    lockProcess.unlock();
};
};
```